# SCL code: tag FUNCTION not defined on TIA

Tags: plc, siemens

I want to create a new SCL function with TIA 15.1. I chose Program blocks => Add new block => Function. When I write the keyword FUNCTION in my file I get the following error: tag FUNCTION not defined. This is the same for others keywords like VAR for example.

My Code:

```
FUNCTION "test" :Void

VAR
    V1: Bool;
END_VAR

END_FUNCTION
```

I searched the web but there is not a lot of documentation on the topic.
Any idea to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the way you need to do this is a little different than the old stuff.  You need to define your variables in the table and and just write code in the editor. You don't add the function, var, var_in, etc.  keywords.

[image]

However, new to V15.1 you can select *text view* under Options->Settings->PLC Programming->SCL->Interface and select *Text view*.  If you create a new function now it will let you enter the variables using var, var_in, etc.  But make sure you create a new function block.  Also, this only works with SCL.

[image]

[image]